# Scheduled Reminders no longer sending

Tags: scheduled-reminders, cv

Scheduled email reminders were working fine on my Drupal/CiviCRM server, then suddenly stopped working, with the last successful mail being sent on 2/11. I don't recall making any significant changes around that time. This is not a cron issue, as the job is executing regularly, it's just returning the following error when it does run.

```
Mar 24 13:12:33  [error] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => exceptionHandler
        )

    [code] => -1
    [message] => DB Error: unknown error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => SELECT *
FROM civicrm_event r
INNER JOIN civicrm_event r ON e.event_id = r.id
INNER JOIN civicrm_contact c ON c.id = e.contact_id AND c.is_deleted = 0 AND c.is_deceased = 0
WHERE (r.id IN ("456")) AND (r.is_active = 1) AND (r.is_template = 0) AND ("20210324131233" <= DATE_SUB(start_date, INTERVAL 11 hour))
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 0
 [nativecode=1066 ** Not unique table/alias: 'r']
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT *
FROM civicrm_event r
INNER JOIN civicrm_event r ON e.event_id = r.id
INNER JOIN civicrm_contact c ON c.id = e.contact_id AND c.is_deleted = 0 AND c.is_deceased = 0
WHERE (r.id IN ("456")) AND (r.is_active = 1) AND (r.is_template = 0) AND ("20210324131233" <= DATE_SUB(start_date, INTERVAL 11 hour))
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 0
 [nativecode=1066 ** Not unique table/alias: 'r']
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="SELECT *
FROM civicrm_event r
INNER JOIN civicrm_event r ON e.event_id = r.id
INNER JOIN civicrm_contact c ON c.id = e.contact_id AND c.is_deleted = 0 AND c.is_deceased = 0
WHERE (r.id IN ("456")) AND (r.is_active = 1) AND (r.is_template = 0) AND ("20210324131233" <= DATE_SUB(start_date, INTERVAL 11 hour))
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 0
 [nativecode=1066 ** Not unique table/alias: 'r']"]
)


Mar 24 13:12:33  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(942): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php(997): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT *\nFROM civicrm_event r\nINN\
ER JOIN civicrm_event r ON e.event_id = r....")
#3 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT *\nFROM civicrm_event r\nINNER JOIN \
civicrm_event r ON e.event_id = r....")
#4 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR::_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -1, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT *\nFROM civicrm\
_event r\nINNER JOIN civicrm_event r ON e.event_id = r....", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php(1928): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php(936): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, "SELECT *\nFROM civicrm_event r\nINNER JOIN civicrm_event r O\
N e.event_id = r....", "1066 ** Not unique table/alias: 'r'")
#7 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php(406): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php(1234): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("SELECT *\nFROM civicrm_event r\nINNER JOIN civicrm_event r ON e.event_id =\
 r....")
#9 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2696): DB_common->query("SELECT *\nFROM civicrm_event r\nINNER JOIN civicrm_event r ON e.event_id = r....")
#10 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1829): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT *\nFROM civicrm_event r\nINNER JOIN civicrm_event r ON e.event_id = r\
....")
#11 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(457): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT *\nFROM civicrm_event r\nINNER JOIN civicrm_event r ON e.event_id = r....")
#12 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1564): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT *\nFROM civicrm_event r\nINNER JOIN civicrm_event r ON e.event_id = r....", TRUE)
#13 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/ActionSchedule/RecipientBuilder.php(251): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT *\nFROM civicrm_event r\nINNER JOIN civicrm_event r\
 ON e.event_id = r....")
#14 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/ActionSchedule/RecipientBuilder.php(150): Civi\ActionSchedule\RecipientBuilder->buildAddlRepeatPass()
#15 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/ActionSchedule.php(353): Civi\ActionSchedule\RecipientBuilder->build()
#16 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/ActionSchedule.php(371): CRM_Core_BAO_ActionSchedule::buildRecipientContacts("3", "20210324131233", (Array:2))
#17 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(207): CRM_Core_BAO_ActionSchedule::processQueue("20210324131233", (Array:2))
#18 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_job_send_reminder((Array:2))
#19 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(150): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:8))
#20 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(81): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:8))
#21 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(22): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("Job", "send_reminder", (Array:1))
#22 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(134): civicrm_api("Job", "send_reminder", (Array:1))
#23 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(66): CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJob(Object(CRM_Core_ScheduledJob))
#24 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(118): CRM_Core_JobManager->execute(FALSE)
#25 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_job_execute((Array:1))
#26 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(150): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:8))
#27 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(81): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:8))
#28 /home/vectorspace/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(22): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("job", "execute", (Array:1))
#29 phar:///home/vectorspace/private/bin/cv/src/Command/ApiCommand.php(74): civicrm_api("job", "execute", (Array:1))
#30 phar:///home/vectorspace/private/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(257): Civi\Cv\Command\ApiCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Sy\
mfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#31 phar:///home/vectorspace/private/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(850): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Ob\
ject(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#32 phar:///home/vectorspace/private/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(193): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Civi\Cv\Command\ApiCommand), Object(Symfo\
ny\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#33 phar:///home/vectorspace/private/bin/cv/src/Application.php(46): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\
\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#34 phar:///home/vectorspace/private/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(124): Civi\Cv\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Compone\
nt\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#35 phar:///home/vectorspace/private/bin/cv/src/Application.php(15): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#36 phar:///home/vectorspace/private/bin/cv/bin/cv(27): Civi\Cv\Application::main("phar:///home/vectorspace/private/bin/cv/bin")
#37 /home/vectorspace/private/bin/cv(14): require("phar:///home/vectorspace/private/bin/cv/bin/cv")
#38 {main}
```

When I disable event 455 and manually execute the scheduled reminders, the same type of error occurs but for event 454, so I don't believe it has to do with event 455. Is it something to do with cv? I installed cv many more months ago and haven't made any changes to it. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: What is you Civi version?

Comment: Civi version 5.32.2, Drupal version 7.77

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears when you have schedule reminder with is repeat ON and 'Also Include' Recipient set. Try applying below patch

```
diff --git a/CRM/Event/ActionMapping.php b/CRM/Event/ActionMapping.php
index 9c8aaae7a5..0874099eb0 100644
--- a/CRM/Event/ActionMapping.php
+++ b/CRM/Event/ActionMapping.php
@@ -136,7 +136,7 @@ class CRM_Event_ActionMapping extends \Civi\ActionSchedule\Mapping {
     $selectedStatuses = (array) \CRM_Utils_Array::explodePadded($schedule->entity_status);
 
     $query = \CRM_Utils_SQL_Select::from("{$this->entity} e")->param($defaultParams);
-    $query['casAddlCheckFrom'] = 'civicrm_event r';
+    $query['casAddlCheckFrom'] = 'civicrm_participant e';
     $query['casContactIdField'] = 'e.contact_id';
     $query['casEntityIdField'] = 'e.id';
     $query['casContactTableAlias'] = NULL;
```